# two oracle queries(one with AND , the other with OR) will return same result?

Tags: oracle

Is there any condition under which the two queries will yield different results?

```
select * from a,b,c where a.id = b.id(+) and a.id=c.id(+);

select * from a,b,c where a.id = b.id(+) or a.id=c.id(+);
```

I think in both cases, it will return the row if the id is in table a.

Comment: They're two totally diffferent queries. One says `WHERE both b.id and c.id match a.id`, and the other says `WHERE either b.id matches a.id or c.id matches a.id`. Use the query that says what it is you're trying to determine.

Answer (score 1):

The second select fails with ORA-01719, Outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN.

Yet another reason to use ANSI JOIN syntax. You couldn't even conceive of this question if you were doing so.